# Is it possible to recover an RSA private key knowing most MSBs of d?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, rsa, private-key

Let's say I have lost a 2048-bit RSA private key but was able to recover a majority of the private exponent *d*, but still missing a couple of the least significant bytes; for the sake of an example, suppose there are ~2000 bits available.

Having modulus *n*, public exponent *e*, and most of the MSBs of *d*, would it be possible to recover the full private key in a feasible amount of time? I have found some algorithms on GitHub that could achieve a similar task, but with the LSBs of *d* available, so I am wondering if the same can be done with MSBs available and, if it is possible, whether there are practical implementations of such a method.

Comment: You're effectively asking if it is possible to brute-force 48-bits - to which the answer is obviously yes!  Is there more nuance to the question?

Comment: Using an attack known as baby-step/giant-step aka meet-in-the-middle it is possible to square-root the brute force work factor and recover d with about 2\*\*25 steps.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not about programming (and I think it has dupes on the cryptography site). Ah [here it is](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/30044/1172). Not possible, you'll have to brute force the rest.